# Windows 2008 R2 migration to XenServer 6.1

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, migration, xenserver

I'm currently testing the migration process of a Windows 2008 server (R2) to Xenserver. 
Currently I have a windows 2008 R2 server running ( Domain controller, dns, ... ) and I want to migrate this to Xenserver.

I tried different approaches but I keep on stumbeling upon a bluescreen when booting the windows VM. I have allocated the same amount of memory and virtual CPU's then the orginal host.

It seems that the VM crashes when it tries to load the disk drivers.

I also tried to use migration tools for XenServer but they where not successfull in completing the job.

My last try was to install the Xen drivers on the host before it was migrated to the Xen VM. The installer then asks to reboot the server but it keeps on rebooting after this point ( I get the login screen and then the server reboots).

Does anyone have any experience with migrations such as this?

My hardware:

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5650  @ 2.67GHz
24Gb RAM
8x600GB SAS 10K Hard disks

I'm using Xenserver 6.1
```

Comment: How are you migrating the server, exactly? Have you performed a P2V of the server?

Comment: I have tried different approaches. First I tried using XenConvert 2.5. This failed into creating the VM. Now at the moment I try to clone the disk to the VM disk. (physicly connecting the disk to the server, mount it in the vm and make a disk clone using clonezilla). This seems to copy all the data correctly but gives me the bluescreen.

Comment: The second method isn't likely to work because of driver differences between the source machine and the destination machine. You might try using Windows Server Backup on the server to capture an image backup and then restore that to a VM.

Comment: And windows server backup will make sure all my data is preserved (I'm not really used to working with windows so I am not familiar with the tools)? I can not afford to lose any data. So I should install a clean VM on the XenServer and then restore using windows server backup ?

Comment: 1. Windows Server Backup can backup the entire server, including the data. 2. If it doesn't work you'll still have the source server intact and you can figure out another method.